# Heroku not found static files Django

Tags: django, heroku, django-staticfiles

I know there are similar questions, but believe me I've gone through every each of them, but still not getting my static files going through. 
Any help is greatly appreciated.

I have all my setting and other codes below.

The capture below shows when I run
**$ heroku run python manage.py collectstatic**
and the erorr I get when I deploy my app.

[Capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnuVO.jpg)

setting.py:

```
import os
import dj_database_url

# this is because I have my setting.py under setting folder
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))

SECRET_KEY = os.environ['secret_key']

DEBUG = False

ADMINS = []
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = '...@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.environ['EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD']
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'registration',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # third party apps
    'crispy_forms',
    # my apps
    'home',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'site2.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.template.context_processors.i18n',
                'django.template.context_processors.media',
                'django.template.context_processors.static',
                'django.template.context_processors.tz',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'site2.wsgi.application'


DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

db_from_env = dj_database_url.config()
DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')


STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.django.GzipManifestStaticFilesStorage'

# registration settings
ACCOUNT_ACTIVATION_DAYS = 7
REGISTRATION_AUTO_LOGIN = True
SITE_ID = 1
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'

# crispy form settings
CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap3'
```

Procfile:

```
web: gunicorn site2.wsgi --log-file -
```

wsgi.py:

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from whitenoise.django import DjangoWhiteNoise

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "site2.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
application = DjangoWhiteNoise(application)
```

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.default.urls')),
    url(r'^', include('home.urls')),
]

if not settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Here is part of my template which is not loading properly:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static from staticfiles %}
<html lang="en">
  <head>

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="{% static 'css/offcanvas.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
 </head>
```

Comment: try {% load static %} instead of {% load static from staticfiles %}

Comment: Not successful!

Answer (score 0):

Change in urls.py:

```
if settings.DEBUG is True:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Or remove static serving code in urls,because whitenose is serving static files, you don't need to serve static files from django in heroku.

Comment: Still not working! I commented out static serving code in url and pushed everyhtin again to heroku, I see it processes static files when I do $ heroku run python manage.py collectstatic [ Post-processed 'js/googlemap.js' as 'js/googlemap.fbc11c53299d.js'] , but still it cannot find .js or .css in my app

Comment: Please change`STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]` to `STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),]`

Comment: Clear cache and hard refresh maybe? I am out of clue... Sorry

Comment: Thanks for your help though.

Comment: @user5772094 If you could avoid post processing, see what happens? Or manually put a file in static directory, try to access it normally using <herokudomain>/static/<filename>

Comment: @Majid did you get to the bottom of this? - I have something similar where I can not change the `/static/` URI I want everything serving from the root of the website but it does not update.

Comment: @StevenChurch
I have vague recollection of this. But, I ended up using AWS S3 to host my static files.

Comment: @Majid tanks for getting back to me. I think I may go down the same route.